# mysql get data into array show double data

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve data from MySQL. But my result shows one result 2 time.

my code

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$rows = Array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  array_push($rows, $row);
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

my result

```
[{"0":"427","id":"427","1":"Alabama","title":"Alabama"}]
```

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array  the default fetch mode is FETCH_BOTH, which fetches string AND numeric keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, mysql_fetch_array will fetch the data in both: array and associative

https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array

To overcome this issue, specify the type:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)){
```

Or

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_array returns both an associative and numeric array, if you would like to only fetch one or the other specify the result type as either MYSQL_NUM or MYSQL_ASSOC